# How to change the column value conditionally

Tags: sql, plsql

I would like to change the column values based on below condition.  Appreciate your expert advice on this.   I need to prefix the respective column value 'F~' if the column is found in col_lst.  Can I achieve this through sql query?

```
Current Output:
row_id|col_lst|col1|col2|col3|col4
1|col1,col2|1|2|3|4
2|col3,col4|A|B|C|D
3|col2|X|Y|Z|P

Expected Output:
row_id|col_lst|col1|col2|col3|col4
1|col1,col2|F~1|F~2|3|4
2|col3,col4|A|B|F~C|F~D
3|col2|X|F~Y|Z|P
```

Regards

Mithil

Comment: Hi Mike, initially my requirement was to bring  the failure columns as col_lst, which i did it using list_agg function.   now another team wants to prefix the failure value as F~<value>  so that they can highlight the failure values in red font.  I would like to do this without changes values in original table.   this approach seems to be complex for me,  thats why seeking an help from experts,  not asking anyone to do my job.

Comment: You posted some sample data, but it is difficult to read. Do you mind fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INSTR function on each column name to determine if it is in the col_lst column.

```
with test_data(row_id,col_lst,col1,col2,col3,col4) as 
   ( select  1, 'col1,col2', '1', '2', '3', '4' from dual union all  
     select  2, 'col3,col4', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' from dual union all  
     select  3, 'col2',      'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'P' from dual 
   )
select row_id
     , col_lst
     , case when instr(col_lst,'col1')>0 then 'F~' || nvl(col1,' ') else col1 end col1 
     , case when instr(col_lst,'col2')>0 then 'F~' || nvl(col2,' ') else col2 end col2 
     , case when instr(col_lst,'col3')>0 then 'F~' || nvl(col3,' ') else col3 end col3 
     , case when instr(col_lst,'col4')>0 then 'F~' || nvl(col4,' ') else col4 end col4
from test_data;
```

However this is a case where you should just tell the other team NO. There is nothing added that they cannot determine from the col_lst themselves, and it serves no purpose except output formatting - which the presentation layer should be doing.

Comment: Hi Belayer,   Thanks for your input.   But this will work if and only if col_lst and columns are static right? In my requirement,  col_lst and columns are dynamically changing.   My result set is produced by joining 100s of tables.  any advice to handle this dynamically?

Comment: To do this dynamically would become a major effort. After determining the col_lit you would then have to generate  SQL containing the case statement for every output column.  Then use execute immediate on the resulting statement then figure out haw to return the result. Best advice: You should just tell the other team NO. You have already given them all the information needed to highlight the columns they just have to look at another column in the result set to do so.